# Change the duration of AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, audiotoolbox

I'm using `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);`

How can I choose the duration of the vibration?

I want only one short vibration, like the "click" from tapping a keyboard button.

Answer (score 5):

You can use for short vibration

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520); // 1521
```